# Is jquery.validate.unobtrusive Bugged?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am trying to get my clienside validation to work when using an ajax request in a jquery ui dialog.

This means I have no submit button and I do no post back. I could not figure out why I could not get it to work.

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146419/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-validate-with-a-jquery-dialog-that-does-an-ajax-s) . I been playing around with it can come to the conclusion is that for whatever reason I need to load up the jquery.validate.unobtrusive with my partial view. It makes no sense to me.

Is this a bug?

---

**Edit**

I also gone and posted the error on the  [asp.net codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8183)

The added benefit to this is that if you wish you can just download my little sample application and try it out.

---

Or you can Follow these steps

1. Make an non empty asp.net mvc 3 application( I am using razor)

   _Layout.cshtml

   @ViewBag.Title

   ```
               <script type="text/javascript">
                   $(function ()
                   {
                       $.get('/home/dialog', null, function (r)
                       {

                           var a = $("#dialog").dialog({
                               resizable: false,
                               height: 500,
                               modal: true,
                               buttons: {
                                     "Delete all items": function ()
                                   {
                                       $('#testFrm').validate().form();
                                   },
                                   Cancel: function ()
                                   {
                                       $(this).dialog("close");
                                   }
                               }
                           }).html(r);
                       });

                       $('#testFrm').live('submit',function (e)
                       {
                           e.preventDefault();
                       });

                   });


               </script>
           </head>

           <body>
               <div class="page">

                   <div id="header">
                       <div id="title">
                           <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
                       </div>

                       <div id="logindisplay">
                           @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
                       </div>

                       <div id="menucontainer">

                           <ul id="menu">
                               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                               <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                           </ul>

                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div id="main">
                       @RenderBody()
                       <div id="footer">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </body>
           </html>
   ```

   ---

   ViewUserControl1 (Partial View) - Stick in Home View folder

   @model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel

   @using (Html.BeginForm("test","Account",FormMethod.Post,new {@id="testFrm"}))
   {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        
   }

---

Index (should exist replace with this)

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

@DateTime.Now

<div id="dialog">
</div>
```

note the dialog id this will be where the ajax request of the partial view gets stored

---

Home Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult test()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public PartialViewResult Dialog()
        {
            return PartialView("ViewUserControl1");
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }




        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

---

TestModel.cs // view model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Required()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

web.config

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />  
  </appSettings>
```

Now run the application. Click "Delete all items" and "Submit Query".

Nothing should happen. No validation pops up for me.

Now go and add this line to the Partial View(ViewUserControl1)

---

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("test","Account",FormMethod.Post,new {@id="testFrm"}))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary()
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
     <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now try again.

It should now come up with validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found some sort of a work around. Even though I think a automatic way should be done for something so basic as making the validation work with partial views

[Work around](http://itmeze.com/2010/10/08/client-side-validation-after-ajax-partial-view-result-in-asp-net-mvc-3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.  When you load a PartialView using Ajax, you must then parse the unobtrusive validation attributes included in the new elements you are loading.

See http://forums.asp.net/t/1651961.aspx/1?Unobtrusive+validation+not+working+on+form+loaded+by+Ajax