# An MVC helper for a validated AJAX form dialog loaded from another page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple edit form. For a particular field, if the user doesn't see what they want, they can click a link, and a request form will pop-up in a new window. (FYI, we support mobile browsers.)

If jQueryUI is available, progressive enhancement intercepts the click, opens a jQuery Dialog, the form is filled, validated, and submitted, where it displays the result and allows dialog close.

**QUESTION**: Is there an 'OEM' or 'Nugettable' MVC helper that implements this simple "ancillary AJAX form" interaction in a downlevel-compatible way?

As far as I can tell, I have to build a whole lot of this from scratch and wire it all up manually, and ASP.NET MVC doesn't even support unobtrusive validation in this scenario. [How to use asp.net mvc 3 jquery validate with a jquery dialog that does an ajax submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146419/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-validate-with-a-jquery-dialog-that-does-an-ajax) Here is an example of building it from scratch for PHP: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/A_2099-jQuery-AJAX-Enabled-Forms-in-Modal-Dialog.html

For example, currently I think I'll need to do these things, and they seem very 'encapsulatable':

- Add an ActionLink with a { target = new }
- Wire a javascript event handler for the link
- Read the link target to set it as a jQuery dialog source
- Reinitialize page validation to overcome the unobtrusive limitation
- Wire the form submit to validation
- Read the form post destination to set it as a jQuery AJAX destination
- Wire form submit to jQuery's AJAX post method
- At the server, return special response for AJAX form posts
- Wire the submit success to an OK dialog
- Wire the submit failure to a dialog redraw

Seems like a lot of effort for an everyday sort of need. Any hints are appreciated.

Shannon

Comment: I see one close vote - if you mark a close vote please tell me why. If this is a duplicate, I'd sure love to know. It is not a duplicate of the link I included. As you can see, I've included *an approach* (although somewhat high-effort), but I'm asking if there is a standardized solution for this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: In MVC3, ajax helpers are deprecated.  Microsoft is supporting only jQuery ajax going forward.  While it's true that what you are suggestiong *could* be made into a helper, there are no so many different client-side javascript libraries, such as knockout, mootools, etc.. that Microsoft doesn't want to artificially limit what can be done client-side by enforcing specific ajax requirements.